# slideshow - return to 1st image

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone know how to add another button to this slideshow that takes the user back to the first image at any given point during the slideshow?

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your following the code in the example you provided, something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnGoFirstSlide').click(function(){
        //hide all
        $('#slideshow-holder .slideshow-content').hide();

        //show the first one :)
        $('#slideshow-holder .slideshow-content:eq(0)').show();
    });

});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow-area">
      <div id="slideshow-scroller">
        <div id="slideshow-holder">
          <div class="slideshow-content">
            <img src="eureka_small.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow-content">
            <img src="wallace_gromit_small.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow-content">
            <img src="dead_like_me_small.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="slideshow-previous"></div>
      <div id="slideshow-next"></div>
    </div>

    <a id="btnGoFirstSlide" href="#">Go to First Slide</a>
</body>
```

Also, if you want to use the built-in animation to go to the first slide try to calculate the ScrollAmount and call the function in the click event:

`$("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks pixelbobby - but can't seem to get it to work, all I get is a blank carousel when I click on the link - so the 'hide' is working but the 'show' isn't. Any ideas?