# Return to 1st image on slideshow

Tags: javascript

I asked this question a few days ago and I really need to solve this problem - please help!!

Does anyone know how to add another button to this slideshow that takes the user back to the first image at any given point during the slideshow?

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [slideshow - return to 1st image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858971/slideshow-return-to-1st-image)

Comment: Ahhhh, @rockinthesixstring - found your post on my other thread - thanks for taking your time to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how they defined a function `showNextSlide`, and then bound it to the `div` id `slideshow-next`; you'll want to define a function `showFirstSlide` that sets `currentSlide` equal to 1 and calls the update functions, and then bind it to whatever button you decide on. e.g.

```
function showFirstSlide()
{
  currentSlide=1;
  updateContentHolder();
  updateButtons();
}
...
$("#slideshow-first").click(showFirstSlide);
```

Comment: Thanks Shad, this is all very new to me - so much to take in! I really appreciate you taking your time to explain this to me, it works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into which div(s) the javascript is animating to move. Then I'd add a button for the control to animate the left position of the starting div back to 0, or however they are structuring it.

Comment: Thanks for you help Atticus - all sorted now, appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad you found what you needed. Good luck with development